# How to get integer from enum in erlang_protobuffs?

Tags: erlang, protocol-buffers

I'm using [erlang_protobuffs](https://github.com/basho/erlang_protobuffs) to parse google protocol. I'd like to know how to turn an enum to integer.

For example, if I defined something like this in protocol:

```
messaage Enum {
     enum Type {
        Type1 = 1;
        Type2 = 2;
      }
      required Type type = 1;
}
```

How do I use erlang code to get 'Type1' is 1 here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in your generated module, but it's for internal use only, maybe your can export it by yourself.

```
enum_to_int(enum_type, 'Type1') -> 1;
enum_to_int(enum_type, 'Type2') -> 2;
```

Comment: I found [gpb](https://github.com/tomas-abrahamsson/gpb) may do it. But when I use it as a dependency, I came out with an error:  Protobuffs library not present in code path! Do you have some ideas?

Comment: Rebar uses another protobuf compiler for *.proto files it finds in the src directory, so maybe you should put the *.proto files in another directory, and find another way to use gpb.